# How to keep focus with input control when value is invalid

Tags: jquery

I have a form with text inputs inside. I want to be able to check some of those inputs , and if there value is not valid i want to keep the focus inside that input untill the user changes it to a valid value. my problem is that in the onblur i added the focus , but untill that happenes the focus goes to another field and then the other field get blured and i get inside a loop..

how can i stay in the first input without triggring the next input onblur?

Thank's In Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of binding the field to `.blur()` try to use `.change()`, this should help keep the loop from happening.

```
$(".someField").change(function(e) {
    var $test = $(this).css("background-color", "");
    if ($test.val() != "Jon") {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $test.css("background-color", "red").focus();
        }, 0);
    }
});
```

**Code example of this on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/dm6Hm/1/).**

Tested in the latest dev channel in chrome, firefox, and IE8

Comment: thank's! I tried your code , and it works - but only when i change the value.. and i want it to work every time not only when it's changed.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This should hopefully put you on the right track:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var lastElement = null;
            var isValid = false;

            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('.validated').blur(function(e) {
                    // validate your input here
                    isValid = false;
                    lastElement = e.target;
                }).click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if(!isValid) $(lastElement).focus();
                });

            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input class="validated" name="foo" type="text" /><br />
        <input class="validated" name="bar" type="text" /><br />
    </body>
</html>
```

Been tested in Firefox 4 Beta 12 and works. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way to change the click into focus? beacuse now it only works if i click another input , and i'm using "tab" key and not mouse click.. tahnk's!!.